# How to QUERY perform operation and then UPDATE on entire table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a large table with around 10 million rows.  I need to take numbers from 2 columns perform some function and then save the result into a 3rd column.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?  The only way I have been able to do this is to QUERY and save the result into a tuple.  Then in a second for loop iterate through the tuple where the result and unique hash is stored and filter by hash and then update.

This is very very very slow though!  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the function doing? You may be able to move a lot of the work to the database

Comment: Depends what you are doing. If you properly describe what operation you need to perform, someone might be able to give you the SQL to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What about an `update`?

```
update t
    set col3 = < some expression here on col1 and col2 >;
```